# how to show the console in qt GUI app with cmake under the windows

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I know how to hide the console window. I just need to add this in my cmakeLists.txt:

```
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "set build type to Release.")
SET(QT_USE_QTMAIN TRUE)
```

As usual, the default one is console. While I remove the two lines in CMakeLists.txt, it won't work. I need the console to show the logs on another PC.

tips: I have tried to check the "run in teminal", it just show me a teminal console in Qt Creator. But I need to run my .exe by double-clicking the icon with a console window.

Is there anyone who knows what happend?

Comment: I once installed Qt, did a few toy examples, and that was it. I don't know Qt. But the above doesn't appear to have anything to do with appearance of console window or not. Instead of console window I would first of all have checked if Qt has some facility for logging. If not, then in Windows just make sure that you build the program with the console subsystem. In Unix-land just run the program from a console.

Comment: This problem is very easy to sovle in qmake, which is just need to add "CONFIG+= console". In cmake, i can not find some document or cmake marco to do this.

Comment: How is this question related to CMake?

Comment: The code in the question is used in CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function

```
void show_console() {
  AllocConsole();
  freopen("conin$", "r", stdin);
  freopen("conout$", "w", stdout);
  freopen("conout$", "w", stderr);
}
```

will show you console window in Windows program compiled with 
`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` flag (versus `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`)